# How to check value exist on column Type on array of object report Control?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular-directive

I need to check column Type value but it not catch or give me message column type exist ON console log

```js
ReportControl: any[] = []
this.ReportControl

value of ReportControl is
[
    {
        "reportId": 2028,
        "fieldName": "offilneURL",
        "reportStatus": "HiddenColumn",
        "columnType": 1
    },
    {
        "reportId": 2028,
        "fieldName": "onlineUrl",
        "reportStatus": null,
        "columnType": 2
    }]
```

I need to check columnType=2 so I write

```js
if (this.ReportControl["columnType"] == 2) {
    console.log("column type exist");
}
```

it does not catch message console log column type exists

Why what is wrong and How to solve that?

Comment: small thing if possible i make isValueexistt = obj["columnType"] == 2 && obj["fieldName"] == 'onlineURL'; and it give me false althought it exist on report control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm seeing from the provided code, `ReportControl` is an array of objects not a simple array and not a simple object. So you need to iterate through that array and then check if `columnType` exists and check its value.

For example you can do the following:

1/ Start by iterating the ReportControl array:

```
this.ReportControl.map((reportElement) => {

});
```

2/ Do you check inside the map method:

```
if("columnType" in reportElement && reportElement["columnType"] == 2) {
    console.log("column type exist in report " + reportElement["reportId"]);
}
```

So the full code will be:

```
this.ReportControl.map((reportElement) => {
    if("columnType" in reportElement && reportElement["columnType"] == 2) {
        console.log("column type exist in report " + reportElement["reportId"])
    }
});
```

There are multiple methods which you can use to achieve this behavior but I think this is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

As you have an array of object you need to check each object for value as below.

```js
var rc = [
        {
            "reportId": 2028,
            "fieldName": "offilneURL",
            "reportStatus": "HiddenColumn",
            "columnType": 1
        },
        {
            "reportId": 2028,
            "fieldName": "onlineUrl",
            "reportStatus": null,
            "columnType": 2
        }
    ];

    var isValueexistt = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < rc.length; i++) {
        var obj = rc[i];
        isValueexistt = obj["columnType"] == 2 && obj["fieldName"] == 'onlineUrl';
        if (isValueexistt) {
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log(isValueexistt);
```

Comment: small thing if possible i make isValueexistt = obj["columnType"] == 2 && obj["fieldName"] == 'onlineURL'; and it give me false althought it exist on report control

Comment: @aboelham, Did my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Since its an array, you have to loop over your elements

```js
var reportControl = [{
    "reportId": 2028,
    "fieldName": "offilneURL",
    "reportStatus": "HiddenColumn",
    "columnType": 1
  },
  {
    "reportId": 2028,
    "fieldName": "onlineUrl",
    "reportStatus": null,
    "columnType": 2
  }
]

let found = false;
for (let i = 0; i < reportControl.length; i++) {
   if (reportControl[i]['columnType'] === 2 && reportControl[i].fieldName === 'onlineUrl') {
       found = true;
       break;
   }
}

if (found) {
   console.log("column type exist");
}
```

Note that this is plain javascript. Since you are using angular, you have to replace `reportControl` with `this.ReportControl`

Comment: small thing if possible i make   isValueexistt = obj["columnType"] == 2 && obj["fieldName"] == 'onlineURL'; and it give me false althought it exist on report control

Comment: check your object again...it has string as `onlineUrl` not `onlineURL`. String matching is case sensitive in javascript